# Copying a column from one CSV file to another

Tags: bash, csv, unix, awk, sed

I have the following CSV files

File 1:

```
"H1","H2","H3"
"AB","1","xyz"
"AC","2","cfd"
```

File 2:

```
"H4","H5","H6"
"GTF","1","23"
"XFD","1","45"
"DRF","2","35"
```

Here H5 in File2 corresponds to H2 in File1(H5 acts as foreign key)

Now I need to add another column H7 in File2 which corresponds to H1 like

File2 desired output:

```
"H4","H5","H6","H7"
"GTF","1","23","AB"
"XFD","1","45","AB"
"DRF","2","35","AC"
```

How do i do this in Unix env using awk, sed.. etc

P.S I cannot use python, perl etc...

Comment: Do you have access to join and GNU sort?

Comment: yes, I have access to them, but the CSV file1 is pretty huge (~3GB).Thanks!

Comment: okay, sort was not necessary, as I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With join and sed:

```
join --header -t, -j 2 file1 file2 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,1.1 | sed '1s/"H1"/"H7"/'
```

Output:

```
"H4","H5","H6","H7"
"GTF","1","23","AB"
"XFD","1","45","AB"
"DRF","2","35","AC"
```

It is important that column 2 in both files (without first line) are sorted ascending.

---

join's options (from `man join`):

> `--header`: treat the first line in each file as field header, print them without trying to pair them
>
> `-t CHAR`:  use CHAR as input and output field separator
>
> `-j FIELD`: join on FIELD of file 1 and file 2
>
> `-o FORMAT`: select colums (FORMAT: file number.column number) while constructing output line

I used sed to replace only in line 1 "H1" by "H7".

Comment: Thank you very much, It'll help me a lot if you can explain me little as I am from java world and the syntax is little difficult to understand.Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if Iam not asking for more, is it possible to achieve this without sorting, as sorting takes extra time and the efficiency is reduced

Comment: Sorting is not necessary when in both files the second column is already sorted ascending, as in your example.